# Is there an R function to merge every dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have hundreds of dataframes, all the same number of rows and columns.

Is there a command that will merge all of them at once, without me needing to name them all?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUAPT.jpg!

All of my datasets look like this. They also all have a naming pattern of 
data_frame_state_county

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211333/discussion-on-question-by-tobin-brooks-is-there-an-r-function-to-merge-every-dat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's image, the `Reduce` is working

```
library(gtrendsR)
keyword <- "domestic violence"
date <- "2020-2-01 2020-04-06"
data_frame_AK_Anchorage <- gtrends(c(keyword), geo = "US-AK-743", gprop = "web", time = date)$interest_over_time
data_frame_AK_Anchorage <- dcast(data_frame_AK_Anchorage, date ~ keyword + geo, value.var = 'hits')


data_frame_AK_Fairbanks <- gtrends(c(keyword), geo = "US-AK-745", gprop = "web", time = date)$interest_over_time
data_frame_AK_Fairbanks <- dcast(data_frame_AK_Fairbanks, date ~ keyword + geo, value.var = 'hits')

out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'date'), 
      mget(ls(pattern = '^data_frame')))
head(out)
#        date domestic violence_US-AK-743 domestic violence_US-AK-745
#1 2020-02-01                           0                           0
#2 2020-02-02                         100                           0
#3 2020-02-03                           0                           0
#4 2020-02-04                           0                           0
#5 2020-02-05                           0                           0
#6 2020-02-06                          89                           0
```